# Delay unattended-upgrades at startup

Tags: 18.04, unattended-upgrades

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 servers in AWS within an AutoScalingGroup. The server images (AMIs) have  unattended-upgrades enabled. I just had a fail-over today and at boot time the unattended-upgrades process took up a fair amount of CPU and extended the startup time of my server significantly.

The AMI is a few months old so probably it tried to apply all security updates in that timeframe. I would however like to delay applying security updates to about 15-30mins after boot time to be able to fail over quickly.

I haven't found any info here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates or searching for options.

Comment: I suppose you could reset the apt-daily and apat-daily-upgrade timers. But you must do so very early during boot; before the network comes up. It might be simpler to disable Unattended Upgrades in your image, and add a job that runs about 15-30 minutes later that enables and runs U-U.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up setting up a systemd timer as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52592734/340885

Create a timer file `/lib/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Delayed start of unattended-upgrades.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target

[Timer]
OnBootSec=120min
```

Then disable the service and enable the timer:

```
systemctl disable unattended-upgrades.service
systemctl enable unattended-upgrades.timer
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. I have a feeling that I have similar problem with u-u getting in a way during boot (In my case it blocks dpkg and prevents ansible from doing it's job). My problems are way up to 22.04LTS and this issue was not addressed. Have you found some solution (except building custom image) that delays/disables it during first boot ? All my attempts failed (including cloud-init scripts).

Comment: Hi Mariusz, initially I was confident that this has worked but later it became clear that it didn't. At least an update was still running at startup

Comment: My solution was to use ansible as last step of terraforming - first step is to disable daemon and second to reboot machine. Afterwards I continue as usual. Reboot is last resort but ansible can handle it (reconnect immediately afterwards) and cloud VM's are quick to reboot. I could not find any other way that will reliably stop u-u. Cheers.

Comment: Cheers @MariuszZieliński